# Assigning text to multiple elements of same class

Tags: jquery

I have multiple elements which I have assigned as class .homeLabel_1

How do I set all their values simultaneously?

I've tried:

```
$('.homeLabel'+i).html("Player1");
```

(where i is a variable from a for loop)

and in the view:

```
 @Html.Label("____", new {@class = "homeLabel_" + @h })
```

('h' is another for loop variable)

Comment: My original selector was actually correct, I had just forgotten to add the _! *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[class^='homeLabel_']")
    .add("[class*=' homeLabel_']")
    .html("Player1");
```

This should update all the HTML content of tags with a class attribute containing the string `'homeLabel_'`.

It should work both in the special case of the target class being the trailing one:

```
<div class="homeLabel_foo"></div>
```

...or in the more general case...

```
<div class="someOtherClass homeLabel_foo"></div>
```

**EDIT**

As [Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6089612/dont-panic) pointed out in comments a better solution would be

```
$("[class~='homeLabel_"+i+"']").html("Player1");
```

where i would be the variable to complete the class name

Comment: I think you forgot to add the second ' in the selectors, perhaps you could add those so I can be sure I'm putting them in the right place.

Comment: @Luca you're missing closing single quotes around the selectors:  `$("[class^='homeLabel_']")`.  I also think you could get rid of the .add() by using `$("[class~='homeLabel_']")`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: yes, but that would generate some false positive occurrencies... Eg.: class="foo_homeLabel_bar"

Comment: Great that works for a general case (although the addclass part is not necessary for me), now how would I add my variable to the selector? eg: $("[class^='homeLabel_]' +i")    
                            .html("Player1");  doesn't work

Comment: @Don'tPanic: nevermind... read the docs with more attention... Will edit the response accordingly

Comment: @Bmills `$(".homeLabel_" + i).html("Player1");`

Comment: wow I've just realised I had the right answer all along in the OP, I had just forgotten to add the _.  So much time wasted on a damn typo!  Thanks for help guys.